# Connect list to Document Set in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: document-set, task-list

Scenario:
We have document library "Incoming correspondence" where we want to store incoming correspondence. sometimes it's more than one document in package, so we want to use DocumentSet to store each package as one record. So far everything is ok, but requirement is to join tasks to each record. I created lookup column to point to "Incoming correspondence". But when I open "Incoming correspondence" DocumentSet welcome page (docsethomepage.aspx) and add task list web part, I can't set connection to Get Filter Values From. So question is, how can i filter list web part based on record id.

Comment: very useful question, I need to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can use native SharePoint filter web part something like "filter by Url" and write there ID or what you want to send as parameter and secondly you should get filter values from this web part.